# Pandas: parse CSV differentiating between the missing value sentinel and a string that happens to equal it

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv, readr

The R readr [`read_csv`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) function allows passing `quoted_na=FALSE`, which allows the parser to distinguish between the unquoted `NA` meaning a missing value, and a quoted `"NA"` meaning a string that happens to equal `NA`.

Is there a way for the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function from Python Pandas to have similar behaviour?

For example, the CSV

```
var_1,var_2
"NA",NA
```

I would like to ideally be parsed as

```
    var_1  var_2
0      NA    NaN
```

The argument `na_values` does not appear to be relevant: it appears to be applied to the strings after CSV parsing that removes the quotes.

For example, something like the below seems to still not be able to distinguish the two cases:

```
pd.read_csv('na.txt', na_values=['NA'], keep_default_na=False)
```

as in, both values are parsed as `NaN`.

Comment: `na_values`, `keep_default_na` and `na_filter` tweaking these parameters should help. Should `NA` and `"NA"` be detected as `NA`?

Comment: @Ch3steR `Should NA and "NA" be detected as NA?` Only `NA` should be detected as `NA` in my case, and `"NA"` should be a string.

Comment: As @Ch3steR mentioned, you can set it the arguments for na values. This [na values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#na-values) link in the docs could help

Comment: @sammywemmy I've investigated that, and I don't think it helps. Have added some details to the question.

Comment: @MichalCharemza Took a while to solve. Nice question +1

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. Using [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `quoting=3`.

```
#test.csv
A,B,C,D
NA,1,2,3
"NA",NA,4,5
6,7,NA,"NA"
```

---

```
 df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv',quoting=3,na_values=['NA'],keep_default_na=False)

     A    B    C     D
0   NaN  1.0  2.0     3
1  "NA"  NaN  4.0     5
2     6  7.0  NaN  "NA"
```

Note :

> If `keep_default_na` is `False`, and `na_values` are specified, only the NaN values specified `na_values` are used for parsing.

Comment: i was racking my brain with the quoting=3 angle. u figured it faster. +1

Comment: @sammywemmy `"` this single quote made us go mad.

Comment: This is helpful, and indeed it does distinguish the cases... but the `quoting=3`: it preserves the quotes around strings? I think in general (at least for my cases) I would like them as type `str`, but without the quotes.

Comment: `df.replace('"NA"','NA')` this can be added but couldn't find anything on how to do it with `read_csv`.Consider adding bounty to attract more answerers. @MichalCharemza